# Select all my tasks or tasks relating to my Accounts or Accounts of users i manage

Tags: soql, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am using SF Mobile SDK to do a `SmartSync`. Because of that, i need to make sure that the results come down in one query.

I want to select data from `Task` where one of the following is true:

- `OwnerId` is a particular user id (**Update** this means, regardless of presence of `What` on the `Task`)
- `What.Type = 'Account'` and `Account.OwnerId` is a particular user id
- `What.Type = 'Account'` and `Account.Owner.ManagerId` is a particular user id

I can get the bottom two like so:

```
SELECT Id, Status, Subject FROM Task 
WHERE 
(What.Type = 'Account' 
   AND WhatId IN 
     (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Owner.Manager.Id = '<USERID>' 
        OR OwnerId = '<USERID>'))
```

However, trying to add an `OR OwnerId = '<USERID>'` to this query results in the dreaded semi-joins error:

> Semi join sub-selects are only allowed at the top level WHERE expressions and not in nested WHERE expressions.

Is there any way to make this work in a single SOQL?

Again, repeat, not APEX, and really need to avoid two queries.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Mobile SDK - is it an option to run SOQL that is slightly too broad and filter on the client side? You can do it with an `AccountId` filter, but the semantics are slightly different.

Comment: @DavidReed I wish. It works like so: you give it a soql query (or, for simpler cases, a set of fields and sObject name) and it hides away all saving/manipulating from you. it is convenient in that it does incremental fetches but is somewhat limiting for cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just do the following:

```
SELECT Id FROM Task
WHERE What.Type = 'Account' AND
(OwnerId = '<UserId>' OR Account.OwnerId = '<UserId>' OR Account.Owner.ManagerId = '<UserId>')
```

No sub-query is necessary here.

Comment: sorry, this will give me different data. If you see the conditions in the question, i need `OwnerId is a particular user id` that means `irrespective of whether there is a What on the record`. Whereas what you posted will only return tasks where what is 'Account'

Comment: Actually, i was able to edit your suggestion a little big so it is now `WHERE OwnerId = '<UserId>' OR (What.Type = 'Account' AND (Account.OwnerId = '<UserId>' OR Account.Owner.ManagerId = '<UserId>'))` and that does seem to work!