# Select custom objects of users i manage

Tags: soql, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Very similar to my previous question here:
[Select all my tasks or tasks relating to my Accounts or Accounts of users i manage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257252/select-all-my-tasks-or-tasks-relating-to-my-accounts-or-accounts-of-users-i-mana)

Which seems to have been `magically` resolved by SF just somehow working.

I have a custom object, let's call it
`MySpecial__c`.

That object like pretty much anything in SF has a `OwnerId` field.

Now, using SOQL from mobile SDK i want to query all `MySpecial__c` entries where i know the owner's manager's Id.

Something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM MySpecial__c where Owner.ManagerId = '<UserId>'
```

Not unexpectedly, i get:

> No such column 'ManagerId' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I can't run this in 2 queries, really, due to how mobile SDK works (further fetches overwrite first fetches, and, additionally, we end up wasting API calls).

I tried doing sth `magical` like my original question, e.g.

`SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM MySpecial__c where User.Id IN ('<UserId>')`

But that just gives me

> Didn't understand relationship 'User' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a join to your advantage here, I believe:

```
SELECT Name, OwnerId FROM MyObject__c WHERE OwnerId IN (
    SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ManagerId = 'someValue'
)
```